# Построение графиков по уникальным значениям DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, matplotlib

Имею [DataFrame](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1anTfGuX_TiWtOG0lTGGUT-e_7PzPdNAT/view?usp=sharing) `ds_pivot`. Для каждого уникального `course_title` нужно построить линейный график, который будет отображать ежемесячный прирост студентов `.cumsum`.

Не могу придумать, как не выводить руками отдельный DataFrame для каждого курса, а сделать это программно.

Что есть сейчас:

```
test = copy.deepcopy(ds_pivot[ds_pivot.course_title == 'Excel Базовый'])
test['cumsum'] = ds_pivot['uniq_st_id'].cumsum()

fig, subplot = plt.subplots()
subplot.plot(test['month_start'], test['cumsum'])
plt.show()
```

Но как рассчитать нарастающий итог внутри всего `ds_pivot` для каждого отдельного курса, а потом построить отдельный `.plot` для каждого курса, не разбивая это всё на куски?

Пробовал через цикл хотя бы вывести данные по количеству студентов в каждый месяц, но и тут не взлетело. А ещё читал, что циклы в `.pandas` - не самое рациональное решение.

```
n = 1
for index, row in ds_pivot.iterrows():
    while n <= 16:
        plt.subplot(4, 4, n)
        subplot.plot(ds_pivot['month_start'], ds_pivot['uniq_st_id'])
        n += 1
```

[image: Вывод цикла по DataFrame]

Comment: а если все курсы на одном полотне нарисовать ? или вам надо каждый курс в отдельном subplot?

Comment: @maxu, на одном полотне даже правильнее будет, мне кажется. Подскажете, как?

Comment: [подсказал ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1152034/211923)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\ds_pivot.csv", index_col=0)  
df["month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["month_start"].astype(str) + "01").dt.to_period("M")
df = df.sort_values(["course_title", "month"])
df["students"] = df.groupby("course_title")["uniq_st_id"].cumsum()

piv = df.pivot_table(index="month", columns="course_title", 
                     values="students", aggfunc="sum")
piv.loc["2018-01":].plot(figsize=(14, 6), grid=True)
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Своим кодом вы мне показали ещё и решение для другой проблемы: заполнить пробелы в месяцах, не знал про `to_period`. И легенду мне раньше приходилось отдельно прописывать, вытаскивая списком значения названий курсов, отдельно задавать цветовую палитру. А тут всё разом.

Осталось разгадать, как разнести каждый курс на отдельный subplot, всё таки нужно для анализа. Это совсем другой путь? Или можно адаптировать этот код?

Comment: @МихаилБойко, Для того, чтобы рисовать каждий график на отдельном subplot, понадобится другое решение - лучше задать новый SO (StackOverflow) вопрос для этого. PS чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) ;)

Comment: готово. Очень боялся задавать вопросы здесь, думал будет негатив. Сообщество гораздо более приветливое, чем я думал, спасибо за помощь.